# Muth-Mills Model

Tags: urban-economics, comparative-statics

I am exploring the Muth-Mills monocentric city model covered in Brueckner's [article](http://www.socsci.uci.edu/%7Ejkbrueck/course%20readings/handbook%20chapter.pdf).

It is given that consumers earn the same income $y$ and buy $q$ housing for a price $p$ at distance $x$ from the centre, while incurring transport costs of $tx$.

Consumers also have a utility function

$$v(c,q)=v(y−tx−p(ϕ)q(ϕ),q(ϕ))=u$$
where $$ϕ=x,y,t,u$$
which they maximise with respect to $q$ subject to the budget constraint

$$c=y−tx−pq$$

The first-order condition implies $\frac{v_2(y−tx−pq,q)}{v_1(y−tx−pq,q)}=p$.

I am able to work out the derivations for $\frac{∂p}{∂γ},γ=x,y,t$ but I was wondering how Brueckner was able to derive that $\frac{∂q}{∂γ}=η\frac{∂p}{∂γ}$.

I believe this question is identical to the second part of the question [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/26182/brueckners-basic-urban-model-comparative-statics) but it has not been answered, which is why this post exists. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the marginal rate of subsitution $MRS = \frac{v_2}{v_1}$. This gives the slope of the indifference curve at the optimal choice. For fixed utility level $u$, this is a function of $q$ alone. The value of $q$ itself is a function of all exogenous parameters (say $\gamma$).

Given this, the first order condition can be written as:
$$
\left.MRS(q(\gamma))\right|_u = p(\gamma).
$$
Taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $\gamma$ gives:
$$
\left.\frac{\partial MRS(q)}{\partial q}\right|_{u} \frac{\partial q}{\partial \gamma} = \frac{\partial p}{\partial \gamma}.
$$
From this, it follows that:
$$
\frac{\partial q}{\partial \gamma} = \eta \frac{\partial p}{\partial \gamma},
$$
where $\eta = \left(\left.\frac{\partial MRS(q)}{\partial q}\right|_{u}\right)^{-1}
$ as given in footnote 3 of the linked article of Brueckner.

Notice that generically, $\eta$ will be function of $q$ and therefore of all exogenous variables (including $\gamma$). As such, it is not necessarily a fixed number.